# How can I change some keystroke on iOS 7 default keyboard? Like Slack

Tags: ios, keyboard, uikeyboard, uikeyboardtype

I use an app called "Slack" somehow they managed to change the return key to be "#" and "@" like in the picture.

I really don't know whether they created a whole new keyboard view that look exactly the same as iOS default keyboard or

It has a way to custom the return button of the default keyboard.

[image: image1]
[image: image2]

Anyone got any idea how can they do this on iOS 7?

Slack has shared it source code for handle message like app [here](https://github.com/slackhq/SlackTextViewController)

Which I still cannot locate where is the functionality to add "@" and "#"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using the Twitter keyboard built in to the iOS SDK.

`[textField setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeTwitter];`

If you're using Interface Builder, select your `UITextField` and go to the Attributes inspector -> Keyboard Type -> Twitter.

[image: Keyboard Type]

Comment: oh!, thanks that means ... one of the default ios. Unfortunately, I haven't used twitter b4.

Comment: Yep!  iOS provides a few custom keyboards for you to use on any `UITextField` or `UITextView` (as seen in my picture above).  Glad I was able to help.